# Alternative to grunt-contrib-less?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, less, grunt-contrib-less

I'm trying to compile a set of .less files, and generate individual source maps in the process. I have about 20 source files currently, and so I'm using [dynamic expansion](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically) to load them all in.

I would then like the file compiled to css (works), and an individual source map generated for each (doesn't work)

```
file_x.less -+--> file_x.css          (YAY)
             |
             |--> file_x.css.map      (NAY)
```

It seems that getting source mapping to work is tricky to start with, but appears not to work at all for [multiple](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less/issues/89), [individual](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less/issues/93) [files](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less/issues/196).

So, does anyone know of an easy, snap-in alternative? If not, my next solution is to try shell out and call lessc natively, but I'd rather not if I can avoid that.

**Edit**: This will be used for both development and production

Comment: For production use or for dev?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any packages that currently do this. With grunt-contrib-less, though the way I ended up solving this issue for myself was by inlining the sourcemaps in the CSS by setting 
`outputSourceFiles: true`

In my experience this is actually the most convenient way to handle your maps anyway. The only downside is that it will require that you have a minifier set up, since inlining the maps will likely more than double the size of your CSS files.

Comment: The problem with this approach (for me) is that our web app is run on embedded devices, and thus the maps are of no use, so I don't want them included. They're only of use for development and/or debugging when run on a PC

Comment: I'm not suggesting shipping the maps in your app, the maps are stored within comments so all you need is a minifier set up to strip the maps in production environments, but preserve them for preprod/local environments. Thats how I solved it anyway and its worked well for me.